# Can we create and import modules in codeskulptor?

Tags: python, python-2.7, codeskulptor

I am writing a code in codeskulptor, I have a question that, can we create a file(module/package) in codeskulptor and can we import it in another program like

```
hello.py

def jj:
   ....
   ....
   print "hello world"
```

In another program

```
import hello
```

can we do that in codeskulptor? If yes,how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

YES, each "file" in CodeSkulptor can be imported.

For example, the "file" http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user29_SdwDlVVu3J4qvLO.py can be imported by `import user29_SdwDlVVu3J4qvLO`.

The good idea is to make `import user29_SdwDlVVu3J4qvLO as my_modulename`. See
http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user29_fg2U0pzeuTFaCPi.py